# Failing to upgrade parrot os 4.7

Tags: linux, operating-system, dependencies, upgrade, parrot

```
$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
[sudo] password for shepie:
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information… Done
Calculating upgrade… Error!
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libc6-dev : Breaks: libgcc-9-dev (< 9.3.0-5~) but 9.2.1-22 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Comment: Sorry, but StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [unix.se]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this:

1. sudo leafpad /var/lib/dpkg/status
2. Remove below lines from document and save it. (You can use ctrl F and delete below lines)

   Package: libgcc-9-dev
   Status: install ok installed
   Priority: optional
   Section: libdevel
   Installed-Size: 13607
   Maintainer: Debian GCC Maintainers debian-gcc@lists.debian.org
   Architecture: amd64
   Multi-Arch: same
   Source: gcc-9
   Version: 9.2.1-19
   Depends: gcc-9-base (= 9.2.1-19), libgcc1 (>= 1:9.2.1-19), libgomp1 (>= 9.2.1-19), libitm1 (>= 9.2.1-19), libatomic1 (>= 9.2.1-19), libasan5 (>= 9.2.1-19), liblsan0 (>= 9.2.1-19), libtsan0 (>= 9.2.1-19), libubsan1 (>= 9.2.1-19), libquadmath0 (>= 9.2.1-19)
   Recommends: libc6-dev (>= 2.13-5)
   Description: GCC support library (development files)
   This package contains the headers and static library files necessary for
   building C programs which use libgcc, libgomp, libquadmath, libssp or libitm.
   Homepage: http://gcc.gnu.org/
3. sudo apt --fix-broken install
4. sudo apt update && apt full-upgrade